# Client SSL certificate verify error in Nginx

Tags: nginx, openssl

We have a ROOT CA ( ADCS ) which we use to signed a client certificate which we use for Client Certificate Verification in Nginx.

This is the relevant Nginx configuration file :-

```
 ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ca.crt;
 ssl_verify_client   optional;

 ssl_crl /etc/nginx/latest.pem;
 ssl_verify_depth 1;
```

Were ca.crt is the ROOT CA certificate and latest.pem is the CRL.

However whenever I try for any certificate ( Working and Revoked ) , it always lead to 400 Bad Request in Nginx.

**Error :-**

*client SSL certificate verify error: (3:unable to get certificate CRL) while reading client request headers*

**Info :-**

Similar configuration seems to work perfectly in Apache however for NGINX it always leads to error. I tried changing the ssl_verify_depth to 1 and 2 but it leads to same error.